# PHP simple dom parser select and remove multiple tags at once

Tags: php

I'm using PHP simple dom parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm. 
I'm able to remove a tag with a specific id by doing

```
$html = str_get_html('<div><div class="two">two</div></div>');     
$e = $html ->find('.two',0);
$e->outertext = '';
echo $html ->outertext;
```

Reading the simple dom api document, i see we can select multiple tags at once by including multiple classes or ids in the find function, but how can we remove all at once.

I tried the following but it doesn't work. It only removes the first class `.two`

```
$e = $html ->find('.two, .three, .four');
$e->outertext = '';
echo $html ->outertext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion.  As per the simple html dom parser documentation,

```
// Find all anchors and images with the "title" attribute
$ret = $html->find('a[title], img[title]');

<div class="mainnavs">
    <ul>
        <li>Tags</li>
        <li>Users</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="askquestion">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Ask Questions
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above HTML I got the expected results,

```
$result = $html->find('[.mainnavs], [.askquestion]' , 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

its works fine for me.

The issue i found in the above code is like your variable name. you content is in $html but you are using $str variable to find the div.

```
$html = str_get_html('<div><div class="two">two</div><div class="three">thomas</div><div    class="four">babu</div></div>');     
$e = $html->find('#two , #three',0);
$e->outertext = '';
echo $html->outertext;
```

Please check out.

Comment: This is not the issue. It's just a typo on SO. Here' how my php file looks like http://eprogramers.com/domparser.txt. It's not working for me. Try it as i have it and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi pinkie, i tested when i change " $html->find('.two,.one',0); " to  $html->find('#two,#one',0);  its working.

Comment: That doesn't work. Can you provide me with your working code.

Comment: $html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<div class="one">testing1</div><div class="two">testing4</div>');
$e = $html->find('#two, #one',0);
$e->outertext = '';
echo $html->outertext;

Comment: This cannot be your working code. You have classes in your html load and yet you are using id's in your code. I don't think you have tested this.

Comment: is this $html->find('[.mainnavs], [.askquestion]' , 0); working for you ?